# Certain list transform

Tags: list-manipulation

I imported three lists

```
list1={{0.01, 0., 0.00242439}, {0.06, 0., 0.00228538}, 
       {0.11, 0.,  0.0018987}, {0.16, 0., 0.00148493}, 
       {0.21, 0., 0.00104764}, {0.26, 0., 0.000575535}, 
       {0.31, 0., 0.000068559}};

list2={{0.01, 0., 0.00242439}, {0.06, 0., 0.00237076}, 
       {0.11, 0., 0.00211971}, {0.16, 0., 0.001817}, 
       {0.21, 0., 0.00150603}, {0.26, 0., 0.00118223}, 
       {0.31, 0., 0.000839701}};

list3={{0.01, 0., 0.00242439}, {0.06, 0., 0.00240639},
      {0.11, 0., 0.00225701}, {0.16, 0., 0.00203365},
      {0.21, 0., 0.00179651}, {0.26, 0., 0.00155504},
      {0.31, 0., 0.00130653}};
```

I wish to add the third column of all lists with each other and keep unchanged two same columns. For example:

```
    result= {{0.01, 0., 0.00727317},{0.06, 0., 0.00706253},...}
```

How do I reach this goal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
list4 = list1;
list4[[All, 3]] = Total[{list1, list2, list3}[[All, All, 3]]];
list4
```

> {{0.01,0.,0.00727317},{0.06,0.,0.00706253},{0.11,0.,0.00627542},{0.16,0.,0.00533558},{0.21,0.,0.00435018},{0.26,0.,0.00331281},{0.31,0.,0.00221479}}

Also

```
KeyValueMap[Append]@Merge[Total][#[[;;2]]->#[[3]]&/@Join[list1,list2,list3]]
```

> same result

Answer (score 6):

```
{#1/3, #2/3, #3} & @@@ (list1 + list2 + list3)
```

> {{0.01, 0., 0.00727317}, {0.06, 0., 0.00706253}, {0.11, 0., 
>     0.00627542}, {0.16, 0., 0.00533558}, {0.21, 0., 0.00435018}, {0.26, 
>     0., 0.00331281}, {0.31, 0., 0.00221479}}

Answer (score 3):

This is a great place to use [`GroupBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html): [`Join`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Join.html) everything together, then group by [`Most`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Most.html) and make lists of all [`Last`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Last.html) elements in a group, then reduce these lists with [`Total`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Total.html):

```
GroupBy[Join @@ {list1, list2, list3}, Most -> Last, Total]
```

> <|{0.01, 0.} -> 0.00727317, {0.06, 0.} -> 
>     0.00706253, {0.11, 0.} -> 0.00627542, {0.16, 0.} -> 
>     0.00533558, {0.21, 0.} -> 0.00435018, {0.26, 0.} -> 
>     0.00331281, {0.31, 0.} -> 0.00221479|>

To get to the OP's shape requirements, use @kglr's trick:

```
KeyValueMap[Append] @ GroupBy[Join @@ {list1, list2, list3}, Most -> Last, Total]
```

> {{0.01, 0., 0.00727317}, {0.06, 0., 0.00706253}, {0.11, 0., 
>     0.00627542}, {0.16, 0., 0.00533558}, {0.21, 0., 0.00435018}, {0.26, 
>     0., 0.00331281}, {0.31, 0., 0.00221479}}

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 + (list2+list3).DiagonalMatrix[{0,0,1}]
```

> {
>
> {0.01, 0., 0.00727317}, {0.06, 0., 0.00706253},
>
> {0.11, 0., 0.00627542}, {0.16, 0., 0.00533558},
>
> {0.21, 0., 0.00435018}, {0.26, 0., 0.00331281},
>
> {0.31, 0., 0.00221479}
>
> }

**In addition:**

```
list1+Inner[Times, (list2+list3), {0,0,1}, List]
```

**Original Answer**

```
list1 + list2.DiagonalMatrix[{0, 0, 1}]+ list3.DiagonalMatrix[{0, 0, 1}]
```